# how to pass multiple conditions in a function in R and returns a dataframe?

Tags: r

This is the question

- Filter for all rows representing the given ticketing class and save the
- new data frame to a variable
- Using this data frame, filter for all rows representing Adult Males
- Find the total number of men and total number of male survivors to
- calculate the survival rate
- Likewise, use the data frame to filter for all Children and Adult Females
- Perform the above calculation for this group as well

```
survival_rate <- function(titanic_class, titanic_data) {
  selected_class <- titanic_data[titanic_data$Class == titanic_class, ]
  selected_male_1 <- selected_class[titanic_data$Sex == "Male" & titanic_data$Age == "Adult" , ]
  return(selected_male_1)
  
}

survival_rate("1st", titanic_df)
```

But it returns me NA values

```
 Class  Sex  Age Survived Freq
NA    <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>   NA
NA.1  <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>   NA
NA.2  <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>   NA
NA.3  <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>   NA
NA.4  <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>   NA
NA.5  <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>   NA
NA.6  <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>   NA
NA.7  <NA> <NA> <NA>     <NA>   NA
```

Titanic_df is supposed to look like this

```
 Class    Sex   Age Survived Freq
1    1st   Male Child       No    0
2    2nd   Male Child       No    0
3    3rd   Male Child       No   35
4   Crew   Male Child       No    0
5    1st Female Child       No    0
6    2nd Female Child       No    0
7    3rd Female Child       No   17
8   Crew Female Child       No    0
9    1st   Male Adult       No  118
10   2nd   Male Adult       No  154
11   3rd   Male Adult       No  387
12  Crew   Male Adult       No  670
13   1st Female Adult       No    4
14   2nd Female Adult       No   13
15   3rd Female Adult       No   89
16  Crew Female Adult       No    3
17   1st   Male Child      Yes    5
18   2nd   Male Child      Yes   11
19   3rd   Male Child      Yes   13
20  Crew   Male Child      Yes    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line you should subset `Sex` and `Age` from  `selected_class` and not from `titanic_data`.

```
survival_rate <- function(titanic_class, titanic_data) {
  selected_class <- titanic_data[titanic_data$Class == titanic_class, ]
  selected_male_1 <- selected_class[selected_class$Sex == "Male" & selected_class$Age == "Adult" , ]
  return(selected_male_1)
}
```

However, you can combine all the 3 conditions together and subset only once.

```
survival_rate <- function(titanic_class, titanic_data) {
  selected_male <- subset(titanic_data, Class == titanic_class & Sex == "Male" & Age == "Adult", ]
  return(selected_male) 
}
```